# some of my website's images are not opening on IPHONES

Tags: html, css

Some of my website's images (which are linked from mysql) are not opening on iphones while others open perfectly. Only the ones inside the manual slideshow are not opening.

html code:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";
$chalet = $_GET['chaletname'];
$q = "select * from search where  ChaletName='$chalet'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>View Chalet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="CSS/viewcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/VChalet.css"> 
        

        <style>
            
            body {
                background-image: url("Images/backg1.jpg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="title">
                <h1><?php echo $chalet ?></h1>
            </div>

        </div> <br> <br>

        <div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;" class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
                <img id ="0" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
                <img id ="1" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
                <img id ="2" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
                <img id ="3" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
                <img id ="4" src="" style="width:100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides( - 1)">❮</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

        </div>
        <br>

        <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
            <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
            
        </div>
<script>
    const slideimages = "<?php echo $row['11'] ?>";
    let s = slideimages.split("/");
    let sLen = s.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < sLen; i++) {
    var image = document.getElementById(i);
    function changeImage() {
    image.src = "Images/" + s[i];
    }

    changeImage();
    }
</script>


<script>
    let slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

css code

```
.slideshow-container {
    max-width:85%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  
  /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
  .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }
  
  /* Caption text */
  .text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: solid;
  }
  
  /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
  .numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
  .dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  
  .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }
  
  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
    
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
```

I tried to change the type and the size of images, Even tried to use the same images which are opening perfectly. But inside the manual slideshow nothing is opening

Comment: Your HTML doesn't include any image sources, so you are presumably using JavaScript to set those. Without seeing that, we can't really help you.

Comment: Can you replace the empty `src` attributes with a real URL (e.g. an image from this site, or Wikipedia or something), so that the code forms a [mre]?

Comment: Also, I've removed the "php" and "mysql" tags, because you haven't shown us any code relating to those; if you think it is relevant, you will need to [edit] to include that in your [mre] as well.

Comment: I edited my post and included the remaining details. Hope this will be helpful thank you

Comment: note: the images are opening on androids without any problem

Comment: What about non-phone devices, especially ones with debug tools like a desktop?